# how can I check whether Intel's AVX is enabled on my computer?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, intel-core-i7, specifications

I have a new Computer with Sandy Bridge CPU, which supports the new AVX instruction set, and Win 7 Ultimate x64 - which is supposedly capable of supporting AVX (i.e., 256-bit SIMD instructions/context-switch saving of YMM registers). The question is: is there any easy way to check whether this is enabled (non-programatically)?

Edit: If it is not enabled, what is the procedure to enable AVX support by the OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft [this will only be supported under Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (slightly offtopic but factual)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff545910.aspx) which is due out this month.  I can't find any detail as to enabling/disabling it - I assume it'll be on by default and your code needs to be written to use it.  Maybe somebody else will have some insight on this?

Comment: That would make sense. I wasn't aware of the fact that the current version doesn't yet support it - I programatically checked for AVX support and realised it's set to off, and my initial interpretation was that it was a bug in my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

To enable or disable AVX instructions you can use this commands:

**Enable AVX:** `bcdedit /set xsavedisable 0`

**Disable AVX:** `bcdedit /set xsavedisable 1`

Open your command prompt and type it, then hit the enter button.

Comment: ha who knew! this fixes the problem of a program trying to use AVX512 on Windows 7, in my case its NVidia's cublasLt64_11.dll